# dxdiag.dll out of date? (Debian Wheezy 64 bit)

Tags: debian, directx

I am currently trying to make South Park: Stick of Truth work on Debian Wheezy (64 bit). Currently, upon launching the game, the game locks whatever workspace I'm on and I have to use xkill to stop it running.

I have reason to believe that the error is related to directx and upon trying to figure the software by running

```
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/dxdiag.exe
```

I receive an error:

```
ERROR: DXDIAGN.DLL IS OUT OF DATE
```

Is there anyone out there who can help me?

Comment: You could try to reset your wine installation by deleting or renaming `~/.wine`. Beware that you will lose all your installed wine software when doing this.

Comment: Have you try to reinstall DirectX runtime?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, same problem, unfortunately.